# How I need to get the occlusion portion of virtual object

Tags: ios

I was doing a project on AR kit.I placed an object in plane before the scene and behind the scene.For behind the scene i used occlusion .How can I get the portion of occlusion covered on object?

I was doing a project on AR kit.I placed an object in plane before the scene and behind the scene.For behind the scene i used occlusion .My need was to specify how much portion of object that was covered with occlusion